# How to connect a Swift application to a local database?

Tags: swift

Well, I have a database on my computer, which I use locally through SQL commands, now my question is.
How can I connect to this database with Swift?
Do the basic operations of CRUD from an iPhone and see them reflected from my computer.
Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of giving SQL commands in the Terminal as you are presumably doing now, write a Mac app and an iOS app both of which maintain a copy of the data locally. (The nature of the local storage becomes immaterial; you can keep using SQLite if that's what you're using.) Now have the apps use CloudKit to reflect your data up into the cloud and down from the cloud whenever it changes. Now they can share data through iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the SQL database to be remote, then I would recommend that you implement a web API which does the CRUD operations. Exposing your database connection details to a client application seems like a bad idea.

Look into SQLite if you are fine with local data.